# How to list all commits and select a specific commit to run in a workflow?

Tags: git, github, workflow

lets say I have this:

```
name: myWorkflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: write
  packages: write

env:
  LOG_LEVEL: ${{ vars.LOG_LEVEL }}
  ACCOUNT_DOMAIN: ${{vars.ACCOUNT_DOMAIN}}
  DATO_INTEGRATION_LAMBDA: ${{ vars.SOMETHING }}
  APPSYNC_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.SOMETHING2}}

defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash

jobs:
  production:
    name: Deploy to Production
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: package
    environment: prod
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Deploy
        uses: ./.github/actions/deploy
        with:
          stage: prod
          aws-region: eu-north-1
          deploy-role-arn: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_ROLE_ARN }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          environment: staging
```

When I go into github I would select "myWorkFloW" and when I select "Run rowkflow" I would get a list of branches to run.

Is it possible to get a list of all the commits currently in a specific branch like main and from that list be able to select a specific commit to deply?